# how to store checked items in an array in CheckedListBox in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, checkedlistbox

i'm storing all checked items in a string this works perfectly for me but i want to store all the checked items in an array with their names.

```
 Dim i As Integer

 Dim ListItems As String

        ListItems = "Checked Items:" & ControlChars.CrLf

        For i = 0 To (ChkListForPrint.Items.Count - 1)
            If ChkListForPrint.GetItemChecked(i) = True Then
                ListItems = ListItems & "Item " & (i + 1).ToString & " = " & ChkListForPrint.Items(i)("Name").ToString & ControlChars.CrLf
            End If
        Next
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
Dim ListItems as New List(Of String)
For i = 0 To (ChkListForPrint.Items.Count - 1)
    If ChkListForPrint.GetItemChecked(i) = True Then
       ListItems.Add(ChkListForPrint.Items(i)("Name").ToString)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need `CheckedItems` then why you are using `Items` instead ? I would recommend to use `CheckedItems`.

I have modified your code a bit and something like this would help you:

```
Dim collection As New List(Of String)()        ' collection to store check items
Dim ListItems As String = "Checked Items: "    ' A prefix for any item

For i As Integer = 0 To (ChkListForPrint.CheckedItems.Count - 1)  ' iterate on checked items
    collection.Add(ListItems & "Item " & (ChkListForPrint.Items.IndexOf(ChkListForPrint.CheckedItems(i)) + 1).ToString & " = " & ChkListForPrint.GetItemText(ChkListForPrint.CheckedItems(i)).ToString)  ' Add to collection
Next
```

Here:

1. `ChkListForPrint.Items.IndexOf(ChkListForPrint.CheckedItems(i))`
   will get the index of the item checked.
2. `ChkListForPrint.GetItemText(ChkListForPrint.CheckedItems(i))` will
   display the text of the item.

So would generate output like: (Assume 4 items in list in which 2 and 3 item is checked)

```
Checked Items: Item 2 = Apple
Checked Items: Item 3 = Banana
```